# Why is $PATH set in sshrc not used?

Tags: linux, svn, ssh, bsd, osx-server

I am trying to setup svn over ssh on an OS X server. In order to do so, I read that I need a wrapper to set umask and - in my case - to set the repository root. A quick and dirty way to do that is to rename `/usr/bin/svnserve` and place a wrapper script at that location. However SIP protects that location from any changes, and I would prefer a cleaner solution anyway.

So I created a wrapper script at `/usr/local/bin/svnserve` and created `/etc/ssh/sshrc` with

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

I have verified that this file gets executed when initiating a remote ssh command from my client by writing to a log file. However, the modified PATH does not seem to get passed to the command environment:

```
ssh hostname 'echo $PATH'
Password:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Am I overlooking something? Or is `/etc/ssh/sshrc` the wrong place to set a path? If so, what's the right place?

---

Other places I've tried: `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`, but none of these seem to get executed in connection with an ssh command.

*Note: It is not an option to change the client behavior (like, for example, adding the desired path to the command).*

Comment: `ssh hostname echo $PATH` expands `$PATH` **before** it starts ssh. It's exactly the same output as just `echo $PATH` locally. To run the test you intended requires `ssh hostname 'echo $PATH'` (with the single quotes, specifically!)

Comment: Goodness! You are right! This changes my question completely to why the $PATH set in sshrc is obviously not propagated to the ssh command environment. Thanks, and I will change the questions accordingly.

Comment: Hmmm. I'd suggest starting by doing some logging in `sshrc`, to see if it's not running, or running and not having any effect (which could happen, for instance, if the `PATH` is overridden again later). `echo "In sshrc" >&2; PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+'; set -x` might be a place to start (whether the `BASH_SOURCE` expansion works will depend on whether your `/bin/sh` is provided by `bash`); that way further commands run by the shell will be logged -- just make sure that `>&2` is used for anything that would otherwise write to stdout.

Comment: By the way -- can you enable the `PermitUserEnvironment` option in `/etc/ssh` on the server? If so, you could set this in `~/.ssh/environment` for the target user (assuming, again, that nothing else is doing an override later).

Comment: (it's also possible that `sshrc` isn't guaranteed to run in the same shell instance that later runs the user-specified command; I'd need to investigate more to confirm that or rule it out -- but if it's the case, the `set -x` log from the above steps will terminate before the remotely-provided command is invoked, which will give us a pretty big clue that it's two different shell instances).

Comment: I did as described, and the set -x log indeed terminates before the actual command (for this purpose I used a test script) is executed. $PATH is set correctly in sshrc, but is obviously reset before entering the command script.

Comment: Excellent! I feel a little bad about writing up an answer incorporating something when you did the legwork to verify it, but that gives us fairly solid ground to stand on. Is `PermitUserEnvironment` a workable solution for you?

Comment: I have tried PermitUserEnvironment and added PATH to ~/.ssh/environment. This works! The PATH set here available in the command script. The drawback is that you cannot *add* a path because $PATH cannot be resolved. 
However, this is not a global but only a per-user solution. I have tried the same with /etc/environment, but the PATH set there does not make it into my command script for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: On Linux, I'd be setting it up via the PAM module configuration. On OS X, on the other hand, I'm not as well-placed to make a suggestion... unless you'd consider it acceptable to configure the server to let `PATH` be passed through from the client.

Comment: ...actually... is this account used *only* for `svnserve`? You might just hardcode it only to ever run the command you specify, ignoring what the client requested. (In a past life, I actually wrote my own SSH server, based on the Paramiko library, for wrapping svnserve... but it did a whole lot of magic, most of which I no longer remember).

Comment: No, the accounts are not only for svnserve. I have seen solutions using the `ForceCommand` option which I think could be an alternative to creating a ~/.ssh/environment for every user.
However, my original question can be answered now, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/sshrc` does not run in the same shell instance with the remotely-issued command, so the PATH update does not persist through.

Some of the available options:

- You can set `AcceptEnv PATH` on the server to configure it to accept a PATH sent by the remote system, and `SendEnv PATH` on the client (in `~/.ssh/config`, or as an argument to ssh passed with `-o`, or in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`).
- In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the server, you can set the option `PermitUserEnvironment` to `yes`; with that done, the variable and value can be added to `~/.ssh/environment` in the individual user's account on the server.
- You can use `ForceCommand` to override the remotely requested command, either with something like `/usr/bin/env PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin svnserve` or simply `/usr/local/bin/svnserve`

Comment: **Option 1** is not actually valid because it requires client side modifications which I had explicitly excluded in my question. **Option 2** could be used, but it requires to add `~/.ssh/environment` for each user which is not elegant. It was not possible to `/etc/environment` instead (may only be read at system start). I went for **option 3** because it gives me maximum flexibility. I use ForceCommand to execute a script that checks if an `svnserve` command has been sent. If so, the svnserve wrapper script is executed instead (passing on the original parameters).