# How to use STDOUT inside /etc/ssh/sshrc without breaking SCP

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to call a program when any SSH user logs in that prints a welcome message. I did this by editing the `/etc/ssh/sshrc` file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ip=`echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1`
echo $USER logged in from $ip
```

*For simplicity, I replaced the program call with a simple echo command in the example*

The problem is, I learned SCP is sensitive to any script that prints to stdout in .bashrc or, apparently, sshrc. My SCP commands failed silently. This was confirmed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442753/2887850

Lots of solutions offered quick ways to check if the user is in an interactive terminal:

- `if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then return; fi` [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88605/449582)

  - Fails becase `[` is not linked
- `case $- in *i*` [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12442753/2887850)

  - Fails because `in` is not recognized?
- Use tty program (same as above)

  - `tty` gave me a bizarre error code when executed from `sshrc`

While all of those solutions could work in a normal BASH environment, none of them work in the `sshrc` file. I believe that is because PATH (and I suspect a few other things) aren't actually available when executing from `sshrc`, despite specifying BASH with a shebang. I'm not really sure why this is the case, but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42737260/2887850) is what tipped me off to the fact that `sshrc` is running in a limited environment.

So the question becomes: is there a way to detect interactive terminal in the limited environment that `sshrc` executes in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `test` to check `$SSH_TTY` (final solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12440287/scp-doesnt-work-when-echo-in-bashrc)):

```sh
test -z $SSH_TTY || echo $USER logged in from $ip
```